# Using local in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, local, racket

```
(define-struct point (x y))


(define (helper lon)
  (* (point-x lon)
     (point-y lon)))

(define (cart lon)

  (cond
    [(empty? lon) 0]
    [else
     (+ (helper (first lon))
        (cart (rest lon))1)]))
```

I am just playing around, making a bunch of functions to see if and where I can use local. This just multiplies point x and y and adds 1 to the result.  Is there a way I can replace the helper function I created here and use local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this seems like a good place for using `local`, as long the `helper` procedure is only being used inside `cart`:

```
(define (cart lon)
  (local [(define (helper lon)
            (* (point-x lon)
               (point-y lon)))]
    (cond
      [(empty? lon) 0]
      [else
       (+ (helper (first lon))
          (cart (rest lon))
          1)])))
```

Also notice that, depending on the language in use, `local` might not be necessary, a simple internal definition will do the trick, too:

```
(define (cart lon)
  (define (helper lon)
    (* (point-x lon)
       (point-y lon)))
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) 0]
    [else
     (+ (helper (first lon))
        (cart (rest lon))
        1)]))
```

Comment: thats the problem. I keep messing up the parens. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh a good IDE will help you with that, after a while you'll forget about the parens ;) BTW I added an additional piece of information to my answer, see the update.